# Generate Scripts to copy views

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I wish to use the Generate Scripts option in SSMS 2008 to copy views on a DEV db to LIVE db.

I set advanced permissions for "Include IF NOT EXISTS = True" & "Script DROP and CREATE = Script DROP and CREATE".

However, when I run this on my LIVE db it complains that:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vw_XXXXXInviteEventDaysA_DELETE, Line 4
Invalid object name 'dbo.vw_XXXXXInviteEventDays'.
```

...I get a lot of occurrences of this.

Would I be right in thinking this error relates to the view replying on another view that is waiting later in script to be created? If so, how do I get around this?

Thanks Paul

Comment: Looks like a forward dependency between `vw_XXXXXInviteEventDaysA_DELETE` and `vw_XXXXXInviteEventDays`. Generate Scripts isn't supposed to let this happen, but sometimes it does. You'll probably need to go through your error list and move the CREATE VIEWs for all the "Invalid Objects" higher up the script. Depending on how numerous and complex your dependency chains are, it could take several iterations of rerunning the script to clear all errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio 2010 Database Project.
Via the feature ["Schema Compare"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you can compare 2 databases and generate deployment script if only you have access to both databases.